# Find a row from a value chain in the same row

Tags: excel, vb.net

I would like to find a row from List of Values in the same row 
for example:

[image]

When I search for `7 8 9 6 5` the result will be row `14`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a match formula and row to find the row all values match:

```
=MATCH(1,INDEX(($E$2:$E$16=E1)*($F$2:$F$16=F1)*($G$2:$G$16=G1)*($H$2:$H$16=H1)*($I$2:$I$16=I1),),0)+1
```

In my example I use the first row to enter the values I search for. The row value is displayed in cell J1:

[image]